# Why field hasn't updated in second method?

Tags: java, apache-spark, web, server, testng

I have created a simple code for testing spark framework below.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import static spark.Spark.post;

public class TestExample {

private boolean flag = false;

@BeforeClass
private void  caseOne(){
    post("/cres/", (req, res) -> {
        flag = true;
        return  res.body();});

}

@Test
private void caseTwo(){
    while (true){
        if(flag == true){
            System.out.println("Finished!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I can't understand why the field `flag` in `caseTwo` method not true?
How to fix it?

Comment: What order are your tests running in?  Also `flag == true` is redundant, it can just be `if (flag)`.

Comment: I have a simple test. I need to check if the request from the client comes to my spark server. The problem is that after running the last method, the server stops and I don't know how not to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

> Why field hasn't updated in second method?

and what should it updated to? why? anything you have coded up that doesn't work?

Each time `@Test` method is invoked, by the test runner, a distinct fresh instance of enclosing fixture (`TestExample` in your case) is instantiated.

You have hardcoded inline, initialization of your `flag` member, and each new instance will have it initialized to `false`.

Comment: Why does the server stop after testing? How to avoid it?

Comment: "*Why does the server stop after testing? How to avoid it?*" - that's another question which has nothing obvious to do with how the `@Test` methods are run by JUnit. Provide log, stack trace, anything that you feel is important for finding the problem that causes your server to stop.